# Delay user access until webapp properly initialized

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

In my vaadin application, I do some initialization work at deployment which takes some time. Is there a way to delay the listening on webserver port until my initialization work is complete?

I am running my application on tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find a better solution, you can always register a filter that will return an error if the server is not ready to serve client requests.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion better solution is not changing webserver configuration, but serve this issue inside your application.

Initially you can quickly register simple view which tells to user that website is not really ready to work:

```
navigator.addView("", new notReadyYetView());
```

After all heavy calculation will be done you can change the main view:

```
navigator.addView("", new mainView());
```

The [documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/navigator/Navigator.html#addView%28java.lang.String,%20com.vaadin.navigator.View%29) says that:

> Registering another view with a name that is already registered overwrites the old registration of the same type.

So everything will be fine. Then you can also register rest views and your application will be working happily.